# Black Berry emulator for Windows Mobile

Tags: blackberry, windows-mobile, blackberry-simulator

Say I want to develop applications for BlackBerry, but I only have a phone with Windows Mobile and for whatever reason I cannot switch to BlackBerry or buy a new phone.

Is there any BlackBerry emulator for Windows Mobile that would allow me to run apps on Windows Mobile 6? I have HTC HD2.

P.S. I'm not interested in emulators for any other platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Blackberry emulator that you can run on a Windows Mobile device.  RIM does provide [Blackberry simulators](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) for most of its devices that you can run on a Windows PC in companionship with your development environment, though.

Comment: Indeed Blackberry SDK provides emulators for specific devices also it provides a MDS Simulator, which  simulates the BIS services.